# unable to initialize Keras model through subclassing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

im trying to create a keras model through subclassing using:

```
class MyModel(Model):
 def __init__(self):
     super(MyModel, self).__init__()
     self.dense1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
     self.dense2 = Dense(10)
 def call(self, inputs):
     x = self.dense1(inputs)
     return self.dense2(x)




model = MyModel(tf.random.uniform([1, 10]))
model.summary()
```

I want it to be equal to this squential api:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

but after running those lines i get:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

can u assist?

Comment: I see your posting history contains many questions (for which I have provided answers) on which you haven't provided feedback. Don't hesitate to vote on the answers if they helped you, or suggest improvements if they haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the input data as arguments to the model constructor. You need to instantiate it

```
model = MyModel()
```

Then you can pass input tensors

```
model(tf.random.uniform([1, 10]))
```

And this will work

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.10745259, -0.21291552, -0.04618738, -0.0118152 , -0.1662825 ,
         0.8145975 ,  0.44216082, -0.07359659,  0.68233466, -0.15205911]],
      dtype=float32)>
```